# Postgresql. Косяк при преобразовании текста в число, Теряются разряды

Tags: postgresql

В таблице есть столбец с идентификаторами вида YYMM.DD№№

```
2101.1601#
2101.1602#
2101.1701#
```

т.е. это дата плюс двузначное число.
Мне нужно создать новый идентификатор на определённую дату.

Регуляркой выбираю последние 3 цифры из идентификаторов за опред дату напр 16.01.2021

```
SELECT REGEXP_MATCHES(номСделки, '\d\d\d(?=\D*$)', 'g')  
FROM db.Сделки 
WHERE номСделки ~ '2101\.16';
```

получаю набор: ( кстати что значат эти фиг скобки при выводе? )

```
{601}
{602}
```

теперь мне нужно изменит их тип на integer.

Пробовал  to_number( val, '999' ); Почему то возвращает 60 вместо 601 куда-то девается один разряд.

Если пишу вручную  to_number( '601', '999' ); результат правильный,

Если пишу вручную со скобками как в рез выборки  to_number( '{601}', '999' );

то опять получаю такой же косяк 60 вместо 601.
В чём дело?

Comment: `to_number(val[1], '999' )`

Comment: *кстати что значат эти фиг скобки при выводе?* [Datatypes - Arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html)

Comment: Попробовал обратиться как к элементу массива - Результат. Ошибка ядра: ОШИБКА:  тип text - не массив и для него нельзя указать индекс элемента

Comment: Вся ф-ияCREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION db.extract_nom(integer)
 RETURNS text
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
id_Сделки ALIAS FOR $1;
output integer;
reg text;
 row_data text;
BEGIN

SELECT to_char( датаЗаявки, 'YYMM\.DD') INTO reg FROM db.Сделки WHERE id=id_Сделки;

--Перебор результатов запроса.
FOR row_data IN SELECT REGEXP_MATCHES(номСделки, '\d\d\d(?=\D*$)', 'g') FROM "db"."Сделки" 
WHERE "номСделки" ~ reg ORDER BY "номСделки" DESC LOOP   

output := to_number(row_data[1], '000');
END LOOP;

RETURN output;
END;
$function$

Comment: Не нужно добавлять текст функции в комментарий. Добавьте в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

> получаю набор: ( кстати что значат эти фиг скобки при выводе? )

В документации это явно  указывается

> The regexp_matches function returns a set of text arrays of captured substring(s)

Т.е. эта функция возвращает не первое подходящее значение, а все (даже если оно только одно) в виде массива.

Я бы на твоём месте решал обратную задачу - стереть ненужное

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_replace('2021.0119687asd', '^\d{4}\.\d{4}', ''), '\D*$', '')
```

или даже (если ты уверен в длине префикса)

```
select regexp_replace(substr('2021.0119687asd', 10), '\D*$', '')
```

---

Ещё, кстати, совет создать дату в таблице сделок, индекс по этой дате и фильтровать по ней, вместо регулярного выражения, потому что с ростом размера таблицы твой фильтр просто убьёт всю производительность. Ну и прямо сейчас заменить `WHERE номСделки ~ '2101\.16';` на `WHERE номСделки ~ '^2101\.16';`